Suitable Category in which Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem Arises Naturally as Canonical Decomposition
By the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem I mean $G/Stab(x) \cong Orb(x)$ given a $G$ action on a set $X$ where $x \in X$. Formally it highly resembles the usual bijection between the image of a morphism and the quotient by its induced congruence (or the kernel thereof), so I'm wondering if one can actually construct a category for which it is precisely that. $G$-$\mathsf{Set}$ is not it, as quotients in it are sets of all orbits. Furthermore, as $G$ (or more precisely, the action) is being modded over, I think the objects should be actions, but what then would be morphisms so that images are all of the form $Orb(x)$?

It's $G\text{-Set}$, you just have to set things up properly. The orbit-stabilizer theorem is not a statement about a $G$-set $X$, it's a statement about a pair $(X, x)$ of a $G$-set $X$ and a point $x \in X$. The forgetful functor $G\text{-Set} \to \text{Set}$ is represented by $G$, so this point $x \in X$ naturally corresponds to a morphism (in $G\text{-Set}$)
$$G \ni g \mapsto gx \in X$$
from $G$ (regarded as a $G$-set in the usual way, left multiplication) to $X$. The image of this morphism is the orbit $\text{Orb}(x)$ of $x$, and the orbit-stabilizer theorem tells us that this morphism exhibits $\text{Orb}(x)$ as the quotient of $G$, as a $G$-set, by the action of $\text{Stab}(x)$ (which acts from the right).

I have a follow up question: does there exist a natural action on the stabilizer? If it were to be thought of as a kernel, one would expect that it to sit inside the category. When $\rho$ in $(G, \rho) \to (X, \sigma)$ is transitive, the conjugation action suffices, but what about when it is not?

@n1lp0tence: I don't understand the question. A natural action of what? What is $\rho$? What conjugation action?

$\rho$ is the left-multiplication action of $G$ on itself, and I am wondering if it induces a natural $G$-action on stabilizers. That is, can stabilizers be taken as $G$-sets? If so, are they a sort of categorical kernel? I can't make sense of my statement on conjugation now - it was probably written when I was sleepy.

@n1lp0tence: in any category with finite limits you can compute what is called the kernel pair of a morphism (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/kernel+pair), which generalizes the kernel. Typically, and in this case, the kernel pair of $f : X \to Y$ is ${ (x, x') \in X^2 : f(x) = f(x') }$. This defines an internal equivalence relation on $X$, also known as a congruence, and the quotient by this equivalence relation (which abstractly is a coequalizer) computes a version of the image $\text{im}(f)$ known as the regular coimage. Then we can furthermore show that congruences on $G$ as a...

...left $G$-set are in one-to-one correspondence with subgroups of $G$, which is is just another way of saying that the quotients of $G$ as a left $G$-set have the form $G/H$. But it's not $H$ itself that forms a $G$-set, but the equivalence relation of being in the same left $H$-coset, regarded as a subobject of $G \times G$.
